# CentOS 6 - Extend disk that has no partitions./

Tags: linux, partitioning

I have a CentOS 6 server (running as a VM on XenServer) that was set up by a previous employee and one of the disks does not have any partitions on it.  I have increased the size of the disk via the XenServer interface and running lsblk does show the new size.  However, I cannot seem to extend the disk (using fdisk) to it's new size.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use%
/dev/xvda3      1.6G  479M  1.1G  32% 
tmpfs           245M  4.0K  245M   1% 
/dev/xvda1      113M   59M   48M  56% 
/dev/xvda7      485M  2.7M  457M   1% 
/dev/xvda2      2.4G  829M  1.5G  36% 
/dev/xvda5      2.4G  1.2G  1.1G  53% 
**/dev/xvdb        99G   92G  1.8G  99%**
/dev/xvdc        99G   60M   94G   1%
/dev/xvde4      222G  195G   16G  93%
```

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE
xvda    202:0    0    8G  0 disk 
??xvda1 202:1    0  120M  0 part
??xvda2 202:2    0  2.5G  0 part 
??xvda3 202:3    0  1.6G  0 part
??xvda4 202:4    0    1K  0 part 
??xvda5 202:5    0  2.5G  0 part 
??xvda6 202:6    0  768M  0 part 
??xvda7 202:7    0  509M  0 part 
**xvdb    202:16   0  300G  0 disk **
xvdc    202:32   0  100G  0 disk
xvde    202:64   0  225G  0 disk 
??xvde4 202:68   0  225G  0 part
```

I know my way around a Linux system quite decently but am I in no way an expert. I have been unable to find an answer to my dillema.  Is is even possible to extend the disk at this point?  Thanks in advance for any help at all!

Answer (score 1):

fdisk doesn't extend *disks,* it only deals with partitions – and your disk doesn't have any, so there's no reason to use fdisk.

Since you already extended the whole disk (i.e. the "xvdb" device as shown by lsblk) and there aren't any other intermediate layers, your next step is to grow **the filesystem**, i.e. allow it to occupy the space it has available. This is what 'df' shows (the filesystem configuration).

fdisk also doesn't extend filesystems, either (if *that* is what you meant by "disk"), so there's no reason to use fdisk here either.

Instead, depending on filesystem type, you'll need **`resize2fs`** for ext4, or **`xfs_growfs`** for XFS, or `btrfs filesystem resize`, or something similar. (Each filesystem has its own tool. Most support online growing, though some require the filesystem to be umounted first.)

Use `df -T` or `lsblk -f` to determine the filesystem type.

Comment: Exactly. The answer is correct. I confirm this as a sysadmin.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add a NEW VIRTUAL DISK and mount it in a place where it will do the most good.  You can find out how to do this by searching "xenserver new virtual disk" on the internetS.
I don't know XenServer but they are all the same.. this is a Linux concept and has nothing to do with your virtualization host (XenServer).

- You need to figure out where all of the space on your Linux installation is being taken.  You probably already know this.  For my example here.. let's pretend it's /home..
- Login as root (aka sudo -i).
- Initially mount the new virtual disk using the mount command.  Create a folder called "home" at the root of it.  You can/will use `rsync` to copy the files from /home/* to "home" on the newly mounted drive.  This should preserve permissions.
- Rename your old /home/ to /oldhome/ just in case something went wrong.
- Use fstab file to mount your new drive as /home/ and reboot.
- If everything looks good, as root, rd /s /q /oldhome

I'm not a Linux god but I have used this method countless times to extend my space in *nix operating systems.  If someone has a critique of how I accomplised this, plese help me make a better post.  I would be happy to amend it.